# Riemann Lebesgue Lemma for locally compact ableian groups

Tags: operator-theory, harmonic-analysis, banach-algebras

I'm looking for a reference (or proof here) of the generalized RL Lemma for LCAGs. One result is that if $G$ is a LCAG then
$$\{ \hat{f} : f \in L^1(G)\} \subset C_0(\Gamma)$$

where $\Gamma$ is the set of characters on $G$ (a character is a group morphism from $G$ to $\mathbb{T}$).

Comment: It follows from a more general theorem for Gelfand transforms (see *Folland - A course on abstract harmonic analysis*, Theorem 1.30)